# Referencing a class object in java

Tags: java, object

Lets say I have a class User:

```
public class User {
    String userID;
    String password;
    Integer connectID;
    String name;

    public User(String Name, String ID, String Pass, Integer connect) {
        userID = ID;
        password = Pass;
        connectID = connect;
        name = Name;
    }

    public String getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public Integer getConnectID() {
        return connectID;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

And I have a section of my code which takes the connectID of a certain object and puts it into a varaible `connectionID = (accounts.get(i)).getConnectID();` where `accounts` is an ArrayList holding all of the objects created. Would there be a way for me to use the `connectionID` variable to relate back to the object again in another method `textWindow.append("localhost." + ... + getDateTime() + " > ");` where the `...` part is the part that I want to use the `getConnectID()` method on.

Comment: Instead of defining connectID as an Integer, why don't you wrap it in an object containing the reference to the User object?

Comment: Can you include the relevant code of your question?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen what other relevant code is there to include?

Comment: Declare `connectionID` with the type of `User`, and only call `getConnectID` when you need it.

Comment: Technically the answer is "yes, but you generally shouldn't." If you need to access the same object's fields multiple times, store that object as a variable, instead of storing the variable and then using it to find the object later. There are some exceptions, such as when a library limits input to a specific field (maybe the ID of an object), yet you still want to be able to get that object using the id (maybe in the case of user input, like a click, keyboard, or touch event). But this is fairly rare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't store `connectionID` as a variable. It is already stored within the `User` object. Instead, store the `User` as a variable so it's contents can be accessed again later:

```
//Before the for loop, in a wider scope, declare the User:
User user;
//Then, in the for loop, initialize it:
user = accounts.get(i);
//As it was declared outside the for loop, it can be accessed later:
textWindow.append("localhost." + "User ID: " + user.getConnectionID() + " at " + getDateTime() + " > ");//or however you wish to format it
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution here is to change the type of `connectionID` from `Integer` to a class you create

```
class ConnectionID {

    private final Integer id;
    private final User user;

    ConnectionID(final Integer id,
                 final User user) {
        this.id = id;
        this.user = user;
    }

    public getUser() {
        return this.user;
    }

}
```

Now you can relate back to the user, given a connection id.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `connectID` is unique to each `User`. You could loop through the `accounts` and compare the `connectID`.

```
public User getUser(int connectID){
    for (User user : accounts){
        if (user.getConnectID()==connectID){
            return user;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```